# keypad storing problem (void value not ignored as it ought to be)

Tags: arduino-ide, c++

I am trying to input 11 numbers only by the use of keypad but the problem is whenever i use this code. It gave me this error.

Here's my code. Help please.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 5);
int table[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    { '1', '2', '3' },
    { '4', '5', '6' },
    { '7', '8', '9' },
    { '*', '0', '#' }
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 2, 3, 17, 16 }; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = { 15, 14, 13 }; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int count = 0;
Keypad kpd = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
char entryStr[13]; // This can hold up to 4 digits
int i = 0;
char n1, n2, n3;
char buf[15]; // i put here***
void setup()
{
    Wire.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(20, 4);
    ask();
}

void loop()
{
    Wire.requestFrom(2, 3); // request 6 bytes from slave device #2 for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {

    int c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
    Serial.print(c);
    table[i] = c;
    Serial.print('\t');
    // print the character } Serial.print('\n'); Serial.print(table[0]); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.print(table1); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.print(table[2]); Serial.print('\n');

    //if(table[0]<=8) //{ //Serial.print("Flame Detected!"); //Serial.println("Level1");
}
void ask()
{

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter no1.:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("(starts with 0)");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    n1 = GetNumber(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);

    Serial.print(n1);

    delay(1);

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter no2.:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("(starts with 0)");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    n2 = GetNumber(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);

    Serial.println(n2);
    delay(1);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter no3.:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("(starts with 0)");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    n3 = GetNumber(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);

    Serial.println(n3);
    delay(1);
    Serial.println(n1);
    Serial.println(n2);
    Serial.println(n3);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("list of numbers ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("will be shown press");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    lcd.print("reset if wrong");

    delay(7000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Numbers Stored:");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("no1.:0");
    lcd.print(n1);
    lcd.setCursor(1, 2);
    lcd.print("no2.:0");
    lcd.print(n2);
    lcd.setCursor(2, 3);
    lcd.print("no3.:0");
    lcd.print(n3);
}
void GetNumber(char* result, const int maxLength)
{
    char key = kpd.getKey();
    int i = 0; // how far through buffer we are
    while (key != '#') {
        switch (key) {
        case NO_KEY:
            break;

        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':

            lcd.print(key);
            if (i < maxLength) {
                result[i++] = key;
                result[i] = 0; // terminating null
            }
            break;

        case '*': // backspace
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                result[i] = 0; // terminating null
            }

            break;
        }

        key = kpd.getKey();
    }

} // end of GetNumber
```

[image]

Comment: Please describe in greater detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetNumber()` function is coded in such a way as to pass the collected value back through the `result` parameter.

> ```
> void GetNumber(char* result, const int maxLength)
> ```

So, when you use the `GetNumber()` function, you pass it `buf`, and after the call returns, you will find the result in the `buf` char array.

However, you appear to be trying to store the result in `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`, which are `char` type variables, and can hold only one character, or a number between `0` and `255`, neither of which can hold an 11-digit string of numbers like you wish.

A `char` is an 8-bit variable. An `int` (on Arduino Uno) is a 16-bit value and can hold at most `32,768`. Even an `unsigned long`, a 32-bit variable of all positive numbers, can hold a maxiumum value of `4,294,967,295`, which gets at most all 9-digit numbers, and some 10-digit numbers.

You would probably be better off holding the numbers as character arrays just like `buf`, and passing those as the first parameter of `GetNumber()` instead of `buf`:

```
char n1[15], n2[15], n3[15];
...
GetNumber(n1, sizeof(n1) - 1);
...
GetNumber(n2, sizeof(n2) - 1);
...
GetNumber(n3, sizeof(n3) - 1);
```

If you do that, then you can get rid of `buf` entirely.

Alternatively, you can keep `buf` as the temporary holder of the incoming string and use `strncpy()` to copy the string from `buf` to `n1` (etc.):

```
GetNumber(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
strncopy(n1, buf, sizeof(n1));
```

This method uses more memory, as you have `buf` taking up space, but it has an advantage that you can later do validation or error checking on the user input before you overwrite `n1` or the others with the new value.

Comment: I already change the code to char[15] n1, n2, n3; but this line give me error it says "expected unqualified-id before '[' token"

Comment: My typo. The declaration should have said `char n1[15], n2[15], n3[15];`

Comment: Thank you I already change it but it gives me another new error to this line  n1 = GetNumber(n1, sizeof(n1) - 1); the error is "incompatible types in assignment of 'void' to 'char[15]' " Thank you really.

Comment: Don't say `n1=`. Please re-read the answer. Take the time to understand what the code does instead of copying-and-pasting blindly, and you will do much better.

Comment: Really sorry and its okay now. Thank you for your help . Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetNumber` function is defined to return void (nothing) while you use it as if it returns the number typed.

change GetNumber to return a int and the end of it do a `atoi` using the buffer and return the result.

Comment: Thank you . Can you give me idea how to do it in my code?Please elaborate thanks a lot.